# How to create a Stanford coreNLP model by training?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, training-data

I'm very new to Stanford's coreNLP and I'm trying to train it by creating a model. I have a folder that has dev.txt, train.txt, and test.txt as well as a jar file named stanford-corenlp-3.5.1-models.jar. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586658/how-to-train-the-stanford-nlp-sentiment-analysis-tool/22635259#22635259) question, I can create a model by executing the following command in the terminal:

```
java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath train.txt -devPath     dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz
```

However, when I run that in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
Error: could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining
```

Can anyone provide step-by-step instructions of how to go about training CoreNLP? I went on the Stanford [website](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a) to see how training is done, but I'm still confused. I thought all I needed to create a model (e.g model.ser.gz) were those three text files and one jar file.

Any help is very appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the CoreNLP jar file in your classpath. So, your java command should look like:

`java -cp /path/to/corenlp/jar:/path/to/corenlp/library/dependencies -mx8g ...`

From the root of the CoreNLP distribution, you can just include all the jars in the directory; e.g.,

`java -cp "*" -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath train.txt -devPath dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz`

Comment: I downloaded the coreNLP master distribution and ran the command from the root, but I still got the same error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining. When I looked through the folders, I found a java file called SentimentTraining.java, but there was no class file for it. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: 1. You should go here and download Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml 2. then run your command out of the folder you download and add -cp "*" as Gabor suggests above 3. "edu/stanford/nlp/sentiment/SentimentTraining.class" is present in the jar stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar 4. You can see what files are in a .jar with this command: "jar -tf stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar"

Comment: I'm going to try that once I get to my computer! Thanks again :) @StanfordNLPHelp

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp finally had the chance to download coreNLP again and I ran the command from the folder. Everything seems to be working and I'm running it as we speak :)