# how to calculate the accuracy when working with corenlp

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

please let me know if I am unclear,

I found some projects in the GitHub written with scala or java with the aim of getting sentiment of the text using corenlp,

I had already tried other approaches to get the sentiment of the text, the approach was like this,
we had training data, so we trained data and make a model then we could evaluate our model with testing data, so the test data had an accuracy,

with regard to this, why no one is interested in calculating the accuracy of the result when they are working with corenlp?

may I ask you some ideas or approach to finding the accuracy when working with corenlp?

some examples:
[sentiment1](https://github.com/fmguler/SentimentAnalysis)

[sentiment2](https://github.com/peoplehum/coreNLP-Sentiment-Analysis-PredictionIO-Template)

[sentiment3](https://github.com/anirudh985/TwitterSentimentAnalysis)

[sentiment4](https://github.com/anirudh985/TwitterSentimentAnalysis)

Comment: really no one knows about this :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I found my answer,

the answere is as simple as this: corenlp is not a library for classification like this,
I mean it reports the analysis of the text.
but we can have both training data and testing data again then evaluate our accuracy. its a bit time consuming but worth it if you need to work with corenlp.

more explanations to how to do it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712795/questions-about-creating-stanford-corenlp-training-models?rq=1)