# Is there a way to use french in Stanford CoreNLP sentiment analysis?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am aware that only the English model is available for sentiment analysis but I found `edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz` in stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar. I'm actually looking at https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP  Is it possible to use this model instead of englishPCFG.sez.gz with CoreNLP and if so, how ?

Comment: You want to do French sentiment analysis? Or French parsing?

Comment: I want to do sentiment analysis on tweets. Since I found this French model I'm wondering if it could be used instead of the English one used for sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 1):

CoreNLP does not include sentiment models for languages other than English. While we do ship French parser models, there is no available French sentiment model to use with the parser.

You may be able to find French sentiment analysis training data. There is plenty of information available about how to do this if you're interested; see e.g. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586658/how-to-train-the-stanford-nlp-sentiment-analysis-tool?rq=1).