# stanford corenlp sentiment training set

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, training-data

I am new to the area of NLP and sentiment analysis in particular. My goal is to train the Stanford CoreNLP sentiment model. I am aware that the sentences provided as training data should be in the following format.

```
(3 (2 (2 The) (2 Rock)) (4 (3 (2 is) (4 (2 destined) (2 (2 (2 (2 (2 to) (2 (2 be) (2 (2 the) (2 (2 21st) (2 (2 (2 Century) (2 's)) (2 (3 new) (2 (2 ``) (2 Conan)))))))) (2 '')) (2 and)) (3 (2 that) (3 (2 he) (3 (2 's) (3 (2 going) (3 (2 to) (4 (3 (2 make) (3 (3 (2 a) (3 splash)) (2 (2 even) (3 greater)))) (2 (2 than) (2 (2 (2 (2 (1 (2 Arnold) (2 Schwarzenegger)) (2 ,)) (2 (2 Jean-Claud) (2 (2 Van) (2 Damme)))) (2 or)) (2 (2 Steven) (2 Segal))))))))))))) (2 .)))
```

I am also aware that I can create the sentiment training model with my own training data using the following command.

```
java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath train.txt -devPath     dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz
```

My question is, do I have access to the training data set that was used to train the model? If yes, then where can I find it? 
Also, is there a way I can append new sentences to the original training data set and create the train model?

Comment: See [How to train the Stanford NLP Sentiment Analysis tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586658/how-to-train-the-stanford-nlp-sentiment-analysis-tool).

Answer (score 0):

The data is available here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/

If you just create a new data set with the same format you can put the files in a directory and set `-trainPath` to that directory.  It will load all files from that directory and train on them.

sample command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -train -numHid 25 -trainPath trees/training-data/ -model model.ser.gz
```