# "Enhancing" CoreNLP Sentiment Analysis Results

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to perform sentiment analysis on a large number of product reviews using CoreNLP (Java).  Overall, I find the accuracy of the analysis to be pretty good.  From what I read, the model I'm using was initially created using movie reviews (I think), so it's not 100% suited for analyzing product reviews.  I was wondering the best way to go about "enhancing" the accuracy of my analysis.

The main thing I was thinking about was that in addition to the text of the product review, I also have a user-provided star rating.  The values range from 1-5, 1 star being the lowest.  I was hoping there was a way to take the star rating into account when generating the sentiment score, since it more accurately reflects the users' feelings on a particular product.  Is there a way I can best have the star rating factor in to the sentiment analysis scoring in CoreNLP?  My analysis code looks something like this:

```
List<ProductReview> reviews = this.reviewRepository.findAll();
        for (ProductReview review : reviews) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref, sentiment");
            props.put("ner.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");

            StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

            int starRating = review.getStarRating();
            String reviewText = review.getTitle() + " : " + review.getReviewText();
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reviewText)) {
                int longest = 0;
                int mainSentiment = 0;
                Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(reviewText);
                String sentimentStr = null;
                List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
                for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
                    Tree sentimentTree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);

                    int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(sentimentTree) - 2;
                    String partText = sentence.toString();
                    if (partText.length() > longest) {
                        mainSentiment = sentiment;
                        sentimentStr = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class);

                        longest = partText.length();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How could I best incorporate the star ratings (or other info, such as votes on the most useful product reviews, etc.) into the analysis being performed by CoreNLP?  Is this something I would have to do separately?  Or is there a way to incorporate the additional data directly into the sentiment analysis engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few enhancements possible.

/1. **Improvised training set and contextual sentiment analysis**:
Some features might get classified as positive in a movie review context, but might be negative in product review context. You shall retrain your data on your context. Method specified [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html)

> Models can be retrained using the following command using the PTB
>   format dataset:
>
> java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25
>   -trainPath train.txt -devPath dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz

A good discussion on training dataset can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586658/how-to-train-the-stanford-nlp-sentiment-analysis-tool).

/2.**Getting the contextual training and testing data :**  Your product reviews data can act as training set as well as testing set. Select the reviews with extreme polarities ( 1 star POOREST, and 5 star GREAT ) as your training data, to improvide further on the content, you can select 1 and 5 star reviews which have been marked as helpful by the community.
Using this data generated your PTB dataset classifying the reviews as POSITIVE and NEGATIVE ( Neutral would be a hard thing to achieve by using 2-3-4 star rated reviews, as they can introduce noise ).

/3. Use 80% of your dataset as training set, and 20% as testing set. The 1 star rated reviews shall mostly get classified as NEGATIVE and 5 star shall mostly get classified as positive.
Post this, you can use the trained model to analyze sentiment of other reviews, **your sentiment score** ( say 0 for negative sentiment, and 5 for very positive sentiment,  or -1 for negative to +1 for very positive) **will have a positive correlation with actual star rating** provided along with that review. If there is a **sentiment disparity**, e.g. a text review comes out as having positive sentiment, but has 1 star rating, you may want to log such cases, and improvise your classification.

/4. **Improvising using other data sources and classifiers**:  [Vader sentiment](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment) (in python ) is a very good classifier specially attuned for social media and things like product reviews. You may or may not chose to use it as a comparative classifier ( to cross match or have double set of your results, from corenlp+vader), but you can surely use its amazon reviews dataset as mentioned [here](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment#resources-and-dataset-descriptions):

> amazonReviewSnippets_GroundTruth.txt FORMAT: the file is tab delimited
>   with ID, MEAN-SENTIMENT-RATING, and TEXT-SNIPPET
>
> DESCRIPTION: includes 3,708 sentence-level snippets from 309 customer
>   reviews on 5 different products. The reviews were originally used in
>   Hu & Liu (2004); we added sentiment intensity ratings. The ID and
>   MEAN-SENTIMENT-RATING correspond to the raw sentiment rating data
>   provided in 'amazonReviewSnippets_anonDataRatings.txt' (described
>   below).
>
> amazonReviewSnippets_anonDataRatings.txt FORMAT: the file is tab
>   delimited with ID, MEAN-SENTIMENT-RATING, STANDARD DEVIATION, and
>   RAW-SENTIMENT-RATINGS
>
> DESCRIPTION: Sentiment ratings from a minimum of 20 independent human
>   raters (all pre-screened, trained, and quality checked for optimal
>   inter-rater reliability).

The datasets are available in the tgz file here:
https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/blob/master/additional_resources/hutto_ICWSM_2014.tar.gz

It follows the pattern `reviewindex_part  polarity  review_snippet`

```
1_19    -0.65   the button was probably accidentally pushed to cause the black screen in the first place.
1_20    2.85    but, if you're looking for my opinion of the apex dvd player, i love it!
1_21    1.75    it practically plays almost everything you give it.
```